# How to make changes in gconf-editor permanent

Tags: gconf, window-buttons

Every time I open my computer, I need to manually unset the value of `button_layout` in gconf-editor in `/apps/metacity/general` to make to the close, minimize and maximize buttons on the right side of the window, but every time I restart my computer it changes back to the left side.

I've tried to right-click the setting and choose "set as default" - but this doesn't work.

How can I make this be permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open *Startup Applications*,

[image]

Press *Add* to add a new startup program, name it, and write into the command box

```
xterm -e gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string menu:minimize,maximize,close
```

press *Save* and it should work as this command will be executed every time you log in.